# error during oauth retrieve request token twitter android?

Tags: android, android-twitter

I am getting error i.e .during oauth retrieve request token twitter android error

while integrating with Twitter.how can i resolve it.Please can any one help me.

Thanking in Advance.

Comment: it works some devices but some devices it show during oauth retrieve request token twitter android error .

Answer (score 0):

Please check:

1. If Internet connection is present on your device
2. If your application has permission android.permission.INTERNET